# javafx dialog with picture as frame

Tags: javafx, dialog

I want to create a "What´s new" dialog with a special frame.

It is a picture of an old frame and that should be without the "normal" frame of java fx.
Inside of the frame should be the message.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
this disables the original frame.